# I am getting DoublerenderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this following code in my controller, the error trace to this piece of code for the error DoubleRenderError.

```
  def build_list(query_string)    
    tasks = query_tasks(query_string)
    @schema2tasklist = schema2tasklist(tasks)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :file => "#{Rails.root}/app/views/tasks/list.html.erb" }
    end 
  end
```

I'm confused where to put the "and return" statement so that only one render is being called at a time.

my list.html.erb also have a render call. I have tried to return from there as well but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you add your "task/list.html.erb" code ?

Comment: This Basically occurs when you call redirect or render within the scope of request(including all filters.).

Comment: You should start by showing us your complete error trace with error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of errors happens when you try to render or redirect multiple times inside a method, check the  followings

1) if your `build_list` calling from another method and does it has a redirect too.

```
def another_method
    #code
    build_list(query_string) 
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

2) does your methods, query_tasks and schema2tasklist has define redirects/renders inside them

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly happening in my exception handling.